# How to format results in Postgres?

Tags: sql, postgresql, recursion

I need to show the location of content within a course that lives in a Virtual Learning Environment (VLE) - basically it is a teaching and learning website that is backed by a Postgres database.

I created the following query that returns the raw data. A sample of this is below

```
WITH RECURSIVE folders AS(
    SELECT ccs.pk1, ccs.parent_pk1, ccs.position, ccs.folder_ind, ccs.title
        FROM course_contents ccs
        INNER JOIN course_main cm ON cm.pk1 = ccs.crsmain_pk1
        WHERE cm.course_id = '<COURSE ID>'
        and ccs.pk1 = '<INDEX>'   -- primary key
UNION ALL
        SELECT cc.pk1, cc.parent_pk1, cc.position, cc.folder_ind, cc.title
        FROM course_contents cc 
        JOIN folders ON folders.pk1 = cc.parent_pk1
    )
    
    SELECT f.*
    FROM folders f
```

**SAMPLE DATA**

| PK1 | PARENT_PK1 | POSITION | FOLDER | TITLE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 11497702 | NULL | 0 | Y | Assessment |
| 11497708 | 11497702 | 0 | N | Using the Assessment Tools |
| 11497709 | 11497702 | 1 | N | Past Exams Papers |
| 11497710 | 11497702 | 2 | N | Using the Assessment Tools |
| 11497711 | 11497702 | 3 | N | Past Exams Papers |

I would like to display it like the table below. Something to note is that there are multiple levels - files in folders, and folders in folders, etc.

| PATH |
| --- |
| Assessment - Using the Assessment Tools |
| Assessment - Past Exams Papers |
| Assessment - Using the Assessment Tools |
| Assessment - Past Exams Papers |

I've used the following line

```
SELECT STRING_AGG(f.title,' - ') AS path
FROM folders f
GROUP BY f.parent_pk1
```

but it displays like

| PATH |
| --- |
| Assessment |
| Using the Assessment Tools - Past Exams Papers - Using the Assessment Tools - Past Exams Papers" |

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Gordon's answer above I have found the answer I was looking for.

I made a few changes to Gordon's code. Please see below. I do need to test this with more data though to see if it fully replicates the content structure.

```
select f.*
from (select first_value(f.title) over (order by position) || ' > ' ||
            f.title
      from folders f
      where f.folder_ind = 'N'
     ) f
```

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm . . . I think you want something like this rather than aggregation:

```
select f.*
from (select first_value(f.title) over (order by position) || '-' || first_value(f.title) over (order by position desc)
      from folders f
     ) f
where folder = 'N';
```

Comment: Hi Gordon,

Thanks for you extremely quick reply. Using your suggestion above, folder could not be found, so taking that as a typo (that field doesn't exist), I changed that to folder_ind and saw the same.

I removed the where clause completely and almost found what I was looking for. The last one was repeated 5 times.

Assessment-Past Exams Papers

Any suggestions with this?

Comment: Please post table descriptions (ddl) for both tables (as text) : courses_main and course_contents and sample data  by table. Your sample does not contain all the necessary columns for your query.

Comment: The names of the columns come from your question.